# GWT depending on browser scroll bar or dynamic resizing of callTable did not work

Tags: java, user-interface, gwt, view, frontend

Iteresiting case which make my work a nightmare in GWT. I try to add to my panel tab with dynamic changed table to add some params by user. Requirements are dynamic adding new elements and that user can overview all of them and eventually correct it. 
I create all that with callTable but in one browser (Chromium or Opera) I can add new elements but in the same time on the same package in mozzila I see scroll bar but canot add dynamically new elements, but if I erase some preloaded one new one appears. Can someone explain to me what exactly goes wrong as it is one package run in incognito mode with erased history and cookies after every session

Maybe screen will be helpfull- param fill added dynamically:
view with new element [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rN9HT.png)
table with scrool bar but without option of adding new element [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EbS2T.png)

And source code:

```
//initial layout and component
            final VLayout customLayout = new VLayout();
            Canvas customComponent = new Canvas();

            //dataprovider modal creation with in memory list
            final ListDataProvider<String> model = new ListDataProvider<>(
                    getProvisioningParameterList());
            final CellTable<String> table = new CellTable<>();

            // create column with data
            Column<String, String> nameColumn = new Column<String, String>(new EditTextCell()) {
                @Override
                public String getValue(String object) {
                    return object;
                }
            };

            //column with delete button
            Column<String, String> deleteBtn = new Column<String, String>(
                    new ButtonCell()) {
                @Override
                public String getValue(String object) {
                    return "x";
                }
            };


            // add column to the table
            table.addColumn(nameColumn, "Custom parameters");
            table.addColumn(deleteBtn, "Click to delete row");

            //initialize table row size
            table.setWidth("100%");

            // Set the field updater, whenever user clicks on button row will be removed.
            deleteBtn.setFieldUpdater(new FieldUpdater<String, String>() {

                @Override
                public void update(int index, String object, String value) {
                    model.getList().remove(object);
                    model.refresh();
                    table.redraw();
                }
            });

            // add a data display to the table which is adapter.
            model.addDataDisplay(table);

            //add Button
            final IButton addButton = new IButton("Add");
            addButton.setIcon("icons/add.png");
            addButton.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                    model.getList().add("fill");
                    model.refresh();
                    table.redraw();
                }
            });

            //add custom config panel with proper view
            ScrollPanel sp = new ScrollPanel();
            sp.setAlwaysShowScrollBars(true);
            customComponent.setContents("Params");
            customComponent.setAutoHeight();
            customLayout.setMargin(15);
            customLayout.addMember(customComponent);
            customLayout.addMember(addButton, 1);
            customLayout.addMember(saveButton, 2);
            customLayout.addMember(table);
```

Answer (score 0):

If someone will still wonder about it I got a solution. I forgot to add ScrollPanel to layout. Edit Additionally I put table into scrollPanel in specific dimentions and that two element structure to main VLayout. Now it works as expected :)